# Replace $ sign in String

Tags: java, string

I used the following line to remove all $ signs and spaces in a given data "DATA":

```
String temp_data = DATA.replaceAll("$", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
```

But it won't remove the $ signs, only the spaces. Does someone have any idea why?

Thanks,
Binyamin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first parameter replaceAll takes is a regex, and the regex engine treats $ as a special character that stands for the end of the line. Escape it with \ like this:

```
String temp_data = DATA.replaceAll("\\$", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Here's an example using replaceAll and replace:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ReplaceAllTest extends TestCase {

    private String s = "asdf$zxcv";

    public void testReplaceAll() {
        String newString = s.replaceAll("\\$", "X");
        System.out.println(newString);
        assertEquals("asdfXzxcv", newString);
    }

    public void testReplace() {
        String newString =s.replace("$", "");
        System.out.println(newString);
        assertEquals("asdfzxcv", newString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works and explains the problem, but there's no need to use `replaceAll(String regExp)` if you want to eliminate single chars.

Comment: @Andreas_D: you're right, I added an example using the replace method.

Answer (score 4):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression - and "$" has special meaning in regular expressions.

Try just `replace` instead:

```
String temp_data = DATA.replace("$", "").replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: But replace takes a single char and puts a single char, so I can't use  it to remove chars, only to replace with other char.

Comment: @MByD: No, there's an overload taking two CharSequences (such as strings). Did you try running the exact code I provided?

Comment: @MByD: Which version of Java are you using? `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` was introduced in 1.5.

Comment: I'm working with eclipse SDK version 3.2.1 and the jvm version is java.vm.version=1.4.2_03-b02

Answer (score 3):

`String.replaceAll` uses a regular expression for matching the characters that should be replaced. In regular expressions however, `$` is a special symbol signalizing the end of the string, so it is not recognized as the character itself.

You can either escape the `$` symbol, or just use the `String.replace` method which works on a plain string:

```
String temp_data = DATA.replace( "$", "" ).replace( " ", "" );

// or
String temp_data = DATA.replaceAll( "\\$", "" ).replaceAll( " ", "" );

// or even
String temp_data = DATA.replaceAll( "\\$| ", "" );
```