# How to replace special character and its next string with one string

Tags: java, string, replace

How to replace the special character  $owner with "hr" and $table_name  with "hr" and $constraint_name with "scma_constraint" in dynamic.
Change

```
"alter table  $owner.$table_name ENABLE constraint $constraint_name;"
```

to

```
"alter table  hr.hr ENABLE constraint scma_constraint;"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of - [Replace $ sign in String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4134316/50776) ?

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace()`

```
String myString = "...";
myString = myStrign
         .replace("$owner", "hr")
         .replace("$table_name", "hr")
         .replace("$constraint_name", "blah");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that what you want but :

```
String str = "alter table $owner.$table_name ENABLE constraint $constraint_name;"
str = str.replace("$owner", "hr")
    .replace("$table_name", "hr")
    .replace("$constraint_name", "scma_constraint");
```

The Javadoc is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29).

The replace() method returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar (without the support of regexp)

The replaceAll() method does the same, but with the support of regexp.

If needed, edit your question with more precision on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all matches, then use `replaceAll()` method and you need to escape special characters like dollar because `replaceAll()` gets a regex as first parameter and if you write `"$owner"` it will mean that your string must start with `"owner"`.

```
myString.replaceAll("\\$owner", "hr")
.replaceAll("\\$table_name", "hr")
.replaceAll("\\$constraint_name", "scma_constraint" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The replaceAll method on String should do the trick.  First store all the key-value pairs in a Map and then do something as follows:

```
for each entry in the map
    myString.replaceAll(entry.key, entry.value)
```

Should be straigtforward to implement.