# Replacing specail character and it rightmost string

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace special character and its next string with one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925426/how-to-replace-special-character-and-its-next-string-with-one-string)

I have the following String:

```
 "Hello $employee.$currency and $bankbalance"
```

My task is replacing `$` and the following String with another String.

I will get more Strings like this in run time and have to scan and identify anything that starts with `$` and should replace with corresponding String.

At run time string with starts with $ should replaced with single string in all it occurences

Comment: You have asked what looks like exactly the same question before with several helpful answers. Perhaps you should try a programming forum in your native language.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest use regex "\$[^. \n\0$]+"
Find the first and last index of the pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\$[^\. \\n$]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string)
if (matcher.find()) {
    start = matcher.start()
    end = matcher.end()
    text = matcher.group()
}
```

and replace that part of the string.

Comment: The pattern.compile("\$[^\. \\n$]+"); throws error like Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Answer (score 0):

```
String st = "Hello $employee.$currency and $bankbalance";
String pattern = "[$]\\w+";
String res = st.replaceAll(pattern,"mystring");
System.out.println(res);
```

Output = `Hello mystring.mystring and mystring`

For [Java regex tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Comment: Yes i know this how to do this different string example first string $employee should replace with one string and $currency will replaced with another string

Comment: st.replace("$employee","str1").replace("$currency","str2");

Comment: Take a look at `Stringutils` also it has a nice collection of String methods.